# CentOS7 OpenSSH won't start with machine and hangs when ran via systemctl

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, openssh, sshd

The SSHD service is enabled on my VM, however it does not start when the machine boots.  Further, if I run `systemctl start sshd` it simply hangs.  If I manually run `/usr/sbin/sshd`, it starts no problem and I am able to connect from an external machine.  I have verified that the `sshd_config` looks fine, and even went as far as removing and reinstalling OpenSSH.  It is important to note that this VM is running a disk image exported from a Google Cloud Compute Engine VM Instance.

Debug is on the highest setting and nothing is being output.  I also have run `journalctl` which returns `-- No entries --`.

I ran `strace -o sshd_strace_output.txt systemctl start sshd` and it appears to get stuck looping over the following few lines:

```
ppoll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, NULL, NULL, 8) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\0019\2\0\0\32\0\0\0\216\0\0\0\1\1o\0.\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/h"..., 705}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 705
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\1\304\2\0\0\33\0\0\0\216\0\0\0\1\1o\0.\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/h"..., 844}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 844
recvmsg(3, 0x7ffc0948a480, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Unfortunately I don't have a good enough understanding of the strace output to really know what is going on.  For further detail here is the full strace output:

```
execve("/bin/systemctl", ["systemctl", "start", "sshd"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x559a0e05a000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77b16c000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=21817, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 21817, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc77b15b000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=43776, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2128920, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc77ad3b000
mprotect(0x7fc77ad42000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc77af41000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7fc77af41000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320i\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=155784, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2255184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc77ab13000
mprotect(0x7fc77ab37000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc77ad36000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x23000) = 0x7fc77ad36000
mmap(0x7fc77ad38000, 6480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77ad38000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/liblzma.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\2000\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=157424, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77b16b000
mmap(NULL, 2249352, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc77a8eb000
mprotect(0x7fc77a910000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc77ab0f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x24000) = 0x7fc77ab0f000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/liblz4.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20%\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=85952, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2179400, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc77a6d3000
mprotect(0x7fc77a6e7000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc77a8e6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x13000) = 0x7fc77a8e6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libgcrypt.so.11", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0u\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=535064, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2621648, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc77a44b000
mprotect(0x7fc77a4c8000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc77a6c7000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7c000) = 0x7fc77a6c7000
mmap(0x7fc77a6cb000, 208, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77a6cb000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \26\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=20032, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77b16a000
mmap(NULL, 2114112, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc77a243000
mprotect(0x7fc77a247000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc77a446000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7fc77a446000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220*\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=88776, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2184192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc77a02b000
mprotect(0x7fc77a040000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc77a23f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0x7fc77a23f000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260l\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=141968, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2208904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc779e0b000
mprotect(0x7fc779e22000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc77a021000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7fc77a021000
mmap(0x7fc77a023000, 13448, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77a023000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340$\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2151672, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77b169000
mmap(NULL, 3981792, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc779a3b000
mprotect(0x7fc779bfd000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc779dfd000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c2000) = 0x7fc779dfd000
mmap(0x7fc779e03000, 16864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc779e03000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpcre.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=402384, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2494984, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc7797d3000
mprotect(0x7fc779833000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc779a33000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x60000) = 0x7fc779a33000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\r\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19288, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109712, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc7795cb000
mprotect(0x7fc7795cd000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc7797cd000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fc7797cd000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libgpg-error.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\n\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19384, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77b168000
mmap(NULL, 2113656, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc7793c3000
mprotect(0x7fc7793c7000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc7795c6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7fc7795c6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\23\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19896, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2113904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc7791bb000
mprotect(0x7fc7791bf000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc7793be000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7fc7793be000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77b167000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77b163000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77b161000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fc77b161880) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc779dfd000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc7793be000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc7795c6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc7797cd000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc77a021000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc779a33000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc77a23f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc77a446000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc77a6c7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc77a8e6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc77ab0f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc77ad36000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc77af41000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
stat("/etc/sysconfig/64bit_strstr_via_64bit_strstr_sse2_unaligned", 0x7ffc0948a6b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mprotect(0x559a0d333000, 20480, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc77b164000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fc77b15b000, 21817)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7fc77b161b50)         = 3189
set_robust_list(0x7fc77b161b60, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7fc779e11790, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fc779e1a5d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7fc779e11820, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fc779e1a5d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x559a0e05a000
brk(0x559a0e07b000)                     = 0x559a0e07b000
access("/etc/system-fips", F_OK)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7ffc0948b910) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7ffc0948b910)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77b160000
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tr"..., 1024) = 309
stat("/etc/sysconfig/64bit_strstr_via_64bit_strstr_sse2_unaligned", 0x7ffc0948b4f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fc77b160000, 4096)            = 0
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106075056, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 106075056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc772c8b000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/proc/self/stat", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc77b160000
read(3, "3189 (systemctl) R 3187 3187 313"..., 1024) = 338
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fc77b160000, 4096)            = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
stat("/proc/1/root", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=241, ...}) = 0
stat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=241, ...}) = 0
stat("/proc/1/root", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=241, ...}) = 0
stat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=241, ...}) = 0
lstat("/run/systemd/system/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=120, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PASSCRED, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PASSSEC, [0], 4) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/run/systemd/private"}, 22) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PEERCRED, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}, [12]) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PEERSEC, 0x559a0e05b810, 0x7ffc0948b5b4) = -1 ENOPROTOOPT (Protocol not available)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ACCEPTCONN, [0], [4]) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"00011"}, [8]) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(3)=[{"\0AUTH EXTERNAL ", 15}, {"30", 2}, {"\r\nNEGOTIATE_UNIX_FD\r\nBEGIN\r\n", 28}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 45
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PEERCRED, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}, [12]) = 0
stat("/proc/1/root", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=241, ...}) = 0
stat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=241, ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fc77b161b50) = 3190
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
pipe2([4, 5], 0)                        = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fc77b161b50) = 3191
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
close(5)                                = 0
ppoll([{fd=4, events=POLLHUP}], 1, NULL, NULL, 8) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLHUP}])
close(4)                                = 0
gettid()                                = 3189
getrandom("\37I\307\354\364~\375\r\256?\323\6\350\\\313\260", 16, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 16
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"OK 2b2d83aeb02c4b349313fff193905"..., 256}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 52
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\4\1 \0\0\0\1\0\0\0\240\0\0\0\1\1o\0\31\0\0\0/org/fre"..., 176}, {"\f\0\0\0sshd.service\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0replace\0", 32}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 208
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\2\1\1&\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\17\0\0\0\5\1u\0\1\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\10\1g\0\1o\0\0!\0\0\0/org/freedesktop/sys"..., 46}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 46
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\0\1\21\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\227\0\0\0\1\1o\0\31\0\0\0/org/fre"..., 168}, {"\f\0\0\0sshd.service\0", 17}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 185
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\1H\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\206\0\0\0\1\1o\0!\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/systemd1/job/21"..., 200}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 200
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\1D\0\0\0\3\0\0\0q\0\0\0\1\1o\0\31\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/systemd1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 180}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 180
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\1H\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\206\0\0\0\1\1o\0!\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/systemd1/job/19"..., 200}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 200
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\1M\0\0\0\5\0\0\0z\0\0\0\1\1o\0\31\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/systemd1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 197}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 197
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\2\1\0012\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\17\0\0\0\5\1u\0\2\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\10\1g\0\1o\0\0-\0\0\0/org/freedesktop/sys"..., 58}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 58
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\0\0019\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\240\0\0\0\1\1o\0-\0\0\0/org/fre"..., 176}, {"\35\0\0\0org.freedesktop.systemd1.Uni"..., 57}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 233
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\2\1\1\10\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\17\0\0\0\5\1u\0\3\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\10\1g\0\1v\0\0\1b\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 16
recvmsg(3, 0x7ffc0948a480, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
ppoll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, NULL, NULL, 8) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\0019\2\0\0\10\0\0\0\216\0\0\0\1\1o\0.\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/h"..., 705}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 705
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\1\304\2\0\0\t\0\0\0\216\0\0\0\1\1o\0.\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/h"..., 844}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 844
recvmsg(3, 0x7ffc0948a480, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
ppoll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, NULL, NULL, 8) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\0019\2\0\0\30\0\0\0\216\0\0\0\1\1o\0.\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/h"..., 705}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 705
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\1\304\2\0\0\31\0\0\0\216\0\0\0\1\1o\0.\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/h"..., 844}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 844
recvmsg(3, 0x7ffc0948a480, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
ppoll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, NULL, NULL, 8) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\0019\2\0\0\32\0\0\0\216\0\0\0\1\1o\0.\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/h"..., 705}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 705
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\1\304\2\0\0\33\0\0\0\216\0\0\0\1\1o\0.\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/h"..., 844}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 844
recvmsg(3, 0x7ffc0948a480, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
ppoll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, NULL, NULL, 8) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
+++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and I am happy to provide any more detail necessary.

**EDIT:**
`/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service` contains the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH server daemon
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=network.target sshd-keygen.service
Wants=sshd-keygen.service

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/sshd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd $OPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What does the `systemd` `sshd.service` file look like?  Are there additional options being passed in the service file that you are not including in your manual test?

Comment: I just updated my initial post to have the contents of sshd.service.  There are no additional options defined in the EnvironmentFile.

Comment: What does `journalctl -ru sshd.service` show after trying to start the `sshd.service` ? I also noticed you have a `Wants` for `sshd-keygen.service`. Does such a service exist on your VM? Try `systemctl status sshd-keygen.service` to see.

Comment: Running ‘strace’ on systemctl isn’t really going to help debug sshd.  Systemctl just sends a dubs message to pid 1 (systemd init) to tell it to do something with the sshd.service unit.  If you want to debug sshd, you’ll have to either attach to a running sshd process or change the service unit to run strace sshd.  However, before doing this, you might want to use other debugging methods like increasing sshd debugging verbosity and watching the journal.

Comment: `journalctl -ru sshd.service` returns `-- No entries --`.
I verified `ssh-keygen.service` does in fact exist, and even removed it from the `sshd.service` file and openssh still wouldn't start.

As far as debug, I have the debug set on the highest level and it is not writing to the logs.  Debug settings are my first step when trying to solve a problem and asking on stackexchange is my last resort.

I'm totally at a loss for what is going on here.  It appears that the service isn't even trying to start.